# How to use httpclient 4.1.x with Maven

Tags: maven-2, apache-httpclient-4.x

httpclient version 4.0 works in my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

...but versions > 4.0 don't compile:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
  <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
  <version>4.1</version>
</dependency>
```

The error:

```
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: unknown:httpclient

Reason: Parent: null:httpmime:jar:null of project: unknown:httpclient has wrong
packaging: jar. Must be 'pom'. for project unknown:httpclient
```

Any idea how to use httpclient 4.1 with Maven?

Comment: An update from Maven 2.2.1 to 3.0.3 solved the problem.

Answer (score 6):

confirmed, use Maven 3.0.x and it works!  here is example from working pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried same configurations 
jar got downloaded from following location which is one of default repos

http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcomponents-client/4.1

Just try after mentioning http://repo1.maven.org/maven2 explicitly in your pom file 
and try using command line

and apache http client 4.1.1 version is also available now

Answer (score 0):

It was a Maven issue: Using Maven 3.0.3 instead of 2.2.1 solved the problem.